# How can I setup the Azure DevOps Server Jira Service Connection?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to integrate Azure DevOps Server 2019 with Jira so I have attempted to add a "Jira service connection". This seems to be an out-of-box connector as I'm not aware of any Jira extensions being installed.

The configuration screen offers "connection name" and "server url", when I enter those values and click ok I get the following error message: Error: The string must have at least one character. Parameter name: endpoint.Authorization.Parameters[configurationId]

Is there any documentation for this connector? I cannot find any...

I have found this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-pipelines-integration-with-jira-software, however it was unclear if this worked for on-premise versions of the applications and didn't appear to be related to the the Jira service connector.